# Visual Studio 2008: Added Project not showing up in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, project, solution

**SOLVED!** For people who are having the same problem this is what i did:

I moved the project away from where Visual Studio though it would be. This forces you to create a new project file there. I did. Then i restarted the program and now my project was visible. I now just moved the original project-files into the now visible folder.

---

I added an project to my solution but it doesn't show up next to all the other imported projects.

And since it doesn't i'm unable to delete it and try again.

However it can be seen if i right click the solution and go to "Startup Project", "Project Dependencies" or "Debug Source File".

I have searched the web for a while now but have yet to find someone with a similar sutiation, how do i solve this?

Comment: check the *target framework* of the project you add and your host project

Comment: IF all else fails, it's time to open your ".sln" file in a text editor to see wtf happened to it. ".sln" files aren't very complicated so you should be able to hand edit it to fix it (*after* backing it up of course!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that this is because the files don't exist. Have you created the project on a network drive somewhere? Have you renamed or moved the folder after adding it to the solution?

Check the paths are right, then double check. Also check your version control to ensure someone hasn't wiped out your changes and left the .sln file intact.

You can edit the .sln directly I suspect to double-check the exact path it's looking for. Verify that path exists too.

Make sure the project you added was created in the same version of Visual Studio too.

Comment: It was all done locally and the folder was indeed there. Check my edit and you'll see that i solved it. I have no idea what happened but it worked after some more playing around.